# DirectX 11 - что означает это предупреждение?

Tags: c++, directx, memory, утечка-памяти

Предупреждение:

> D3D11 WARNING:    Live ID3D11InputLayout at 0x0000000003FE3A20,
>   Refcount: 0, IntRef: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #433:
>   LIVE_INPUTLAYOUT]

Имею одну копию `layout` в статической переменной, на момент предупреждения у неё выполнен `release` и она равна `nullptr`. Ещё имею вот это при создании `layout`:

```
zGlobalVariables::Context->IASetInputLayout(InputLayout);
zGlobalVariables::Layout = InputLayout;
InputLayout = nullptr;
```

`release` не зову, так как буду его звать в ситуации, описанной выше. Из предупреждения следует, что:

1. Количество ссылок равно нулю - никто на него не ссылается(это и так ясно).
2. Внутренний счётчик ссылок равен нулю.

То есть нигде никто на `layout` не ссылается, отладочный слой это подтверждает, но говорит, что объект живой - как так? Нужно удалить все ссылки на один объект(задний буфер), чтобы изменить его размер, у меня около десятка таких предупреждений, и везде количество ссылок 0. Вот так:

```
ID3D11Debug *DebugDevice = nullptr;
HRESULT hr = Device->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Debug), reinterpret_cast<void **>(&DebugDevice));
hr = DebugDevice->ReportLiveDeviceObjects(D3D11_RLDO_DETAIL);
DebugDevice->Release();
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это предупреждение, в случае нулевого числа ссылок, означает, что ресурс корректно удалён. Отладочный метод будет его выдавать в любом случае(просто я сомневался). Я закончил на удалении аппаратных текстур Direct3D. Удалил всё, что имел, и метод `ResizeBuffers` вернул S_OK. Сейчас буду всё возвращать, чтобы выяснить, что удалять было не нужно.